# Do my Shimano 7900 Dura Ace chainrings need replacing?

Tags: maintenance

Basically today I had a bizarre suggestion; someone told me that my Dura Ace 7900 crankset (a 53 chainring) needs replacing because some teeth are worn from use.

I ask myself, is that possible? I've had Dura Ace before and the only thing I've heard about changing every once in a while is the (rear) cassette.

What do I have to do? Change my chainring, buy a new one for 200 euros? 
I believe it is impossible for people to buy cassettes *and* chain rings every year. I am not a pro cyclist to ride many thousands of kilometres a year!

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles! Sorry, but we really prefer answers be posted here, not emailed out of the site where it won't ever help anybody else.

Comment: My general rule of thumb is that a chain is good for 2000 miles, a rear cassette for 5000 miles, and a front sprocket for 10,000 miles.  How many miles/km do you think you might have on the bike?

Comment: If the chainring is visibly deformed to the extent that someone is, independently, pointing it out to you, then that is feasible. It will wear down over time and if you've been particularly hard on it - many bad gear changes for example - a few thousand km is not out of the question.

Comment: A photo might help us see if the wear is visible. If you're getting bad shifts, check that everything is clean and there's no dirt inside the cable housings. Sounds obvious, but I took my bike to the LBS in exasperation trying to tweak my gears. They replaced the cable housing and it's all smooth and easy! Maybe you're not as clueless as me. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You should be ok for training, but when the time comes to replace the chain the worn chain rings will speed up the degradation of the new chain. You should try to replace the drivetrain components all at once or you won't get maximum value for money. But this can be expensive and overkill if you're not cycling competitively.

Comment: It's relatively cheap (& effective) to replace the chain several times between cluster/ring replacements.  So long as you don't let the chain go too far the wear on the other components will be minimized.

Comment: If you really want to prolong your chain ring life, it's supposed to be worth rotating several chains. So you use a chain until it's about a third worn, swap for a new chain, use that, use a third new chain, then go back to the first chain, use it for the second third of its life, etc.. Once all three chains are end of life, the chainrings will need changing too, but because the rings wear to fit the chain, they'll have worn much less than if you just used three chains until worn.
I've never bothered, but then again I'm not paying for Dura-Ace rings either.

Comment: Thank you all youve been very very helpfull.I thank you all.The thing is that having the idea that my casette is damaged making me crazy.Because i have some bad change gears with my cassete.Everything is so expensive but I will fix them all.Damn this cycling the most expensive sport :) thank ou all again